# Reducir los Mb de una Imagen de la Galería en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy con el tratamiento de unas imagenes. Tengo dos ImageView en un Fragment a los cuales les agrego imagenes que tomo de la galeria de images. Si las imagenes son demasiado grandes, la aplicacion se detiene, supongo que por haber demasiada informacion en el Fragment. Como podria reducir de 5Mb que tienen las imagenes de media a unos 1000kb de media para asi tener varias imagenes en el Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);




    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){


        if(ButtonActiveLeft==true){
            form4path1=data.getData();
            imageViewLeft.setImageURI(form4path1);
            if (form4path1!=null){

            }


        }
        else if(ButtonActiveRight==true){
            form4path2=data.getData();
            imageViewBack.setImageURI(form4path2);


        }


    }



    switch (requestCode){

        case COD_SELECCIONADO :


            if(ButtonActiveLeft==true){
                form4path1=data.getData();
                imageViewLeft.setImageURI(form4path1);

                try {
                    bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(),form4path1);
                    imageViewLeft.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            else if(ButtonActiveRight==true){
                form4path2=data.getData();
                imageViewBack.setImageURI(form4path2);


                try {
                    bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(),form4path2);
                    imageViewBack.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


    }








}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar esta libreria añadela a tu gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

y desde tu onActivityResult la utilizas asi

```
Glide.with(imageViewBack.context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(File(localPath.filePath))
                    .apply(options)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .into(imageViewBack)
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio mucho